# Trying to use friendly name on Kendo Grid pop up editiing

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that uses pop up editing due to the large amount of fields in my model. However the model does not use friendly. When I bind a column, I can simply use .Title("Some Title") to make the column have a friendly name. When I pop up the editor, I get the names from my model. I have looked at this demo by telerik http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup that clearly shows the pop up using friendly names and not the bound names. I just have no clue how they are doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably using the `[Display(Name="Some Nice Title")]` on the properties. part of the Data Annotations collection. (That's what I usually do with pop up editors)

Then using the `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.[Your Property here]);` within the editor window itself (if you are providing a custom template rather than getting the grid to create one for you)

I am assuming you are using the MVC wrappers so this should work perfectly fine.

If you can provide a cut down version of your model then I am sure I could add some example code for you. If this isn't clear enough.

Comment: @Contristo Glad this helped you out.